# PartitionBy removes special characters in PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (df) with 3 columns (col1 string, col2 int, col3 string)  as below but millions of records:

```
Test's  123   abcdefgh
Tes#t   456   mnopqrst  
Test's  789   hdskfdss
```

When I am trying to do partitionBy using PySpark to write the data with the below statement, the special characters in the Col1 is lost and replaced with ascii characters while creating directories in hdfs. Is there any way that the special characters are retained and included in the directories path while writing this dataframe to hdfs?

```
df.write.partitionBy("col1","col2").text(hdfs_path)
```

Please let me know if I have confused and need more details. I am using Spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to have special characters in file path. Some of the special characters are not supported by the URIpath in hadoop shell, it is recommended to use only characters which are mentioned in JAVAURI:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

A character is encoded by replacing it with the sequence of escaped octets that represent that character in the UTF-8 character set: `'` is replaced by `%27` and `#` by `%23`.

If you want to read from the file names using the original string, just use urllib's `quote` funtion:

```py
import urllib

file_name = "Tes#t"
url_file_name = urllib.parse.quote(file_name)
print (url_file_name)
print (urllib.parse.unquote(url_file_name))

    Tes%23t
    Tes#t
```